# VBA refer a string inside Dir to get partial filename

Tags: excel, vba, windows, automation

I am trying to reference a string variable inside Dir command to get the partial filename but it doesn't seem to pick up the exact filename. Can someone help and correct the syntax?

```
str = Format(MonthName(str, True)) ' this gives me previous month, DEC
myPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\DEC_Imports.xlsx`
fname = Dir(myPath "*" & str & "*") ' -- here is where I'm trying
```

Thanks and any help is appreciated!

This is returning blank but expecting the exact filename.

Comment: `myPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\"`, for starters.

Comment: Yep, I included a back slash and removed the filename but the issue is in the last line still.

Comment: `Dir(myPath & str & "*")`

Comment: By the way, prefer a different variable name than `str`, since that shadows the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

Comment: Sure, will do. But looks like Dir is checking only on the right side of the filename. I tried to replace "*" on both sides but I get "Expected list separator or )"

Comment: `myPath & str & "*"` becomes `C:\Users\user\Deskstop\Dec*`. The `*` will match `_Imports.xlsx`.

Comment: Thanks BigBen. You are correct for the given scenario. But in a few cases, the month abbreviation may come in the middle of the filename because the Broker may add some prefixes so I wanted to check both sides of the filename.

Comment: Then `Dir(myPath & "*" & str & "*")`.

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Thanks for the quick help, BigBen!